# Ruby On Rails *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/ruby: Permission denied (13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having error on my ruby on rails new setup.

This is the: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /usr/local/lib/ruby: Permission denied (13)

It's totally fresh installation.
Server info:
Rackspace, RAM 1GB
Mongo Db

Ruby: ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
Rails: Rails 3.2.12
Gems: 1.3.7

Please help

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure this file is executable? If so, what is it doing inside lib folder, not bin? Can you show `ls -la /usr/local/lib/ruby`?

Comment: Are you using rbenv to install ruby? (if not, I recommend it on the server)

Comment: Hi Jesse, Thanks for you reply,I am not sure, if it is to go in lib folder or not.. i am totally new to ruby :) & bashing my head to figure out what i must do to run it.. Please let me know what i can do  to make it working.

Comment: Also, Any Idea:

rails server
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/faraday-0.8.6/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_BOUNDARY
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ostatus-0.0.12/lib/ostatus.rb:1: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'